# sp mixing in $N_2$ vs sp mixing in CO

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, electronic-configuration

We were first taught that in B, C and N the bonding $\sigma_{2s}$ orbital repels with the bonding $\sigma_{2p}$ orbital which cause the energy level of $\sigma_{2p}$ orbital to increase. This increase in energy level causes the $\sigma_{2p}$ to switch positions with $\pi_{2p}$orbitals. We were told that this phenomenon is known as sp mixing.

But then we were taught the MOT diagram of CO. Over here, it looks like the bonding $\sigma_{2s}$ and the bonding $\sigma_{2p}$ orbital are not repelling each other but rather mixing (or hybridising?) with each other.  So what does exactly happen during sp mixing? Do the orbitals repel or mix?
[image]

[image]

My main doubt is that why are the 2s orbitals in N2 only contributing to the 2s sigma bonds, while the 2s orbitals in CO are contributing to both non bonding orbitals and sigma sp?
Why isn't a sigma sp being formed in N2?

Comment: Can you cite a source for the concept that the orbitals repel each other?

Comment: @Andrew I don't particularly have a resource since my teacher gives us notes ( We dont use textbooks, only workbooks). But I think this site is also saying the same thing? https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-albany-chemistry/chapter/molecular-orbital-theory/   correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything in the linked article about MOs repelling each other. It says that the change in energy is due to s-p mixing, and that mixing is less in O,F and Ne because of the larger starting energy difference between the s and p orbitals which they attribute to the pairing energy of filled p orbitals (I would add to that the higher effective nuclear charge). Nothing about repulsion between MOs

Comment: @Andrew maybe repel is the wrong word, but I can't find sources that say that the s and p orbitals mix (hybridize) either. Most of the stuff online say that the orbitals interact and influence their energies. What exactly does interact mean here?

Comment: @Andrew For example- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_diagram%23s-p_mixing&ved=2ahUKEwjK_Oi57vL6AhWdgGMGHSfABKkQ0gIoAXoECBcQAg&usg=AOvVaw3JkXQSOUP8kAi9xHW-Jl9h

Comment: Although it's called "s-p mixing", it isn't the s and p *atomic* orbitals mixing, but rather the *molecular* orbitals derived from them, specifically the $\sigma_s$ and $\sigma_p$. This is different from hybridization, as it results in a change in energy of the eigenfunction orbitals of the energy operator, whereas hybridization creates an alternative orbital basis set that are not eigenfunctions.

Comment: @Andrew Why does this happen in CO but not in N2?

Comment: @Pumpkin_Star the site you linked (https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-albany-chemistry/chapter/molecular-orbital-theory/) has the answer to your question: "...the 2p orbitals for O, F, and Ne are higher in energy than the 2p orbitals for Li, Be, B, C, and N. Because of this, O2, F2, and N2 only have negligible s-p mixing (not sufficient to change the energy ordering), and their MO diagrams follow the normal pattern..."